# How to deserialize XML child elements

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I have the following class:

```
[XmlElement]
public class Container
{
   [XmlAttribute]
   public string Name { get; set; }

   //TODO: set xml serialization attribute.
   public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

What attribute should I use on the Itmes property to have it deserialize the child-elements into the list given the following XML:

```
<Container Name="Container1">
   <Item>
   <Item>
   <Item>
</Container>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `CollectionDataContract`. Your `Item` is a collection inside container, so they should be part of Container instead of a separate list property.

```
[CollectionDataContract(Name = "Container", Namespace = "")]
public class Container : System.Collections.Generic.List<Item>
{
     [XmlAttribute]
     public string Name { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(Name = "Item", Namespace = "")]
public class Item
{
   // Properties
}
```

Comment: Good point, but it would redefine the question. I might need your tip in another scenario.

Answer (score 1):

This is the attribute I needed:

```
[XmlElement("Item")]
```